# Misunderstanding of Chern character

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I'm trying to understand the basics of the chern character before I get much more involved.

I'm really confused since (3) and (5) in the picture below seem to conflict. One says that addition goes to multiplication and one says that addition goes to addition.

Do I misunderstand the product in (3)? It seems like (5) is definitely right. Maybe the author meant addition in (3)?

[image]

Comment: [Images of text are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged). You also haven't mentioned the source of the text you're referring to, but it looks like Wikipedia. Please add a source too!

Comment: $(5)$ hold for the Chern character, not the total Chern class. I believe this is a mistake.